# Can i passing parameter to jquery, after inserting a new row which is in different php

Tags: php, jquery

this is my jquery coding

```
$('#btnKirimPesan').click(function(){
        $('#bantu').load('kirim_pesan.php', {'emailPenerima': $('#emailPenerima').val(), 'isiPesan': $('.isiPesan').val()});
    });
```

then this is on kirim_pesan.php

```
<?
include('../../config/buka_koneksi_db.php');
$query = "INSERT INTO pesan(emailPenerima, emailPengirim, statusBaca, isiPesan, waktuPesan) VALUES((SELECT emailUser FROM user WHERE MD5(emailUser) = '".$_POST['emailPenerima']."'), '".$_SESSION['email']."', 0, '".$_POST['isiPesan']."', NOW('d/m/Y/H/i/s'))";
$hasilQuery = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_affected_rows()>=1)
    $hasil = 1;
    else
            $hasil = 0;
include('../../config/tutup_koneksi_db.php');
?>
```

The jquery coding and query inserting new row is in different file. I want to reload a div in jquery file(it's php file) if only `$hasil = 1;`, if its == 0, I'll show dialog which say "your message has not been sent"...how can i do it??please help me...>,<...thx before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `load()` jQuery method places the HTML returned by the server inside the element. So, assuming that `#bantu` is the ID of the div where you want to show the message, changing your `kirim_pesan.php` file to the following should do it:

```
<?
include('../../config/buka_koneksi_db.php');
$query = "INSERT INTO pesan(emailPenerima, emailPengirim, statusBaca, isiPesan, waktuPesan) VALUES((SELECT emailUser FROM user WHERE MD5(emailUser) = '".$_POST['emailPenerima']."'), '".$_SESSION['email']."', 0, '".$_POST['isiPesan']."', NOW('d/m/Y/H/i/s'))";
$hasilQuery = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_affected_rows()>=1)
    echo "Message sent!";
else
    echo "Your message has not been sent.";
?>
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery `load()` you are loading the contents of the output of `kirim_pesan.php` in the element with ID `#bantu`. So anything you `echo` for example in you php script, will appear in your `#bantu` element:

```
if(mysql_affected_rows()>=1)
{
    $hasil = 1;
    echo "Data has been added";
}
    else
{
    $hasil = 0;
    echo "Your message has not been sent";
}
```

Note that for a dialog to pop-up, you will need some additional javascript but if you are already using dialogs, that should not be that hard, just use the output of the php script.